# Html.ActionLink problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I am trying to provide a link to filter search results.

```
    <%= Html.ActionLink("Filter Results", "Index", new { page = Model.RestaurantList.PageIndex(), searchText = Model.SearchText, useFilter = true, filterOption = Model.FilterOption, filterText = Model.FilterText }, null)%>
```

The controller definition is as such

```
 public ActionResult Index(int? page, string searchText, bool useFilter, string filterText, string filterOption)
```

However when I debug this the values are not set properly, even the useFilter variable.

My link is rendered localhost/home/index/true?page=0

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code segment looks fine.  I think there are 2 possible errors:

1. Wrong route information: check the
   routes.MapRoute(...) calls in
   global.ascx.cs/vb file to make sure
   a route for Home#Index action is
   properly configured
2. Wrong controller: try use the overload of ActionLink which explicitly specifies a controller

If you still can't make it to work, you might want to post more info (like route mapping code, name of view/controller)

Comment: It was a route problem. I overlooked the order I was adding the routes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it should work.

Have you verified that the model fields you are passing to the ActionLink actually contain data?

Answer (score 0):

> However when I debug this the values are not set properly, even the useFilter variable.
>   My link is rendered localhost/home/index/true?page=0

I think your useFilter parameter is actually rendered. Its mapped to the route I guess.

Try to set a hardcoded value for searchText

> 

If it shows up, then you did not set your model in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation.

Something like this:

```
Html.ActionLink("Click me", "Index", "Student", 
        { ID = theclass.StudentID }, null)
```

always renders as

```
localhost/myapp/Student/Index/1234
```

While I was experimenting, I noticed that `Index` part disappeared from the URL if I change the parameter name from `ID` to something like `IDX`

```
localhost/myapp/Student/?IDX=1234
```

It turns out that the parameter name `ID` is special because of the default route entry in Global.asax.cs (which sets up RESTful business object access pattern)

To work around this, I simply stopped using `Index` to take an ID and instead defined another method like this:

```
public ActionResult Detail(int ID)
```

After all, per RESTfull design principle, `Index` is meant for showing "listing of business objects" or some sort of collection of business object, not a single business object.  So passing business object ID to `Index` is kind of violating the pattern.

Instead of twist the arm and force my awkward design, I changed to natural way.

I believe the best practice for designing `Index` entry point is to keep it parameter-less, or pass only filtration/sorting parameters.